# Writing a Hash Table to File and Restoring From File in C++

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am working on an assignment for school using hash tables in a structure program. Part of the assignment is writing a hash table composed of 20 primary buckets and 10 overflow buckets, each with 3 slots composed of a key and data field to disk and then restoring from it. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for strcpy()

using namespace std;

typedef char STR10[10+1];
typedef char STR20[20+1];

struct SLOT
{
  STR10 key;
  STR20 data;
};

struct BUCKET
{
  SLOT entry[3];
  int count;
  BUCKET* overflow;
};

struct HASHTABLE
{
  BUCKET pBkt[20];
  BUCKET oBkt[10];
};

void WriteHTtoDisk (HASHTABLE ht, char *HashDisk);
void ReportHT (HASHTABLE ht, char * when);

int main()
{
    int maxP = 20;
    int maxO = 10;
    int maxS = 3;
    HASHTABLE ht;

    STR10 mKey;
    STR20 mData;

    FILE * inFile;
    inFile = fopen("DATAIN.dat","rb");
    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        cout << " DATAIN file access error ... \n";
        cout << " Terminating application ... \n ";
        cout << " Press any key ... \n ";
        return -100;
    }
    char crLF;

    while (!feof(inFile))
    {
        fscanf(inFile,"%10c%20c\n",mKey,mData);
        mKey[10] = mData[20] = 0; // add string terminators
        printf(" MyKey: %10s\n MyData: %20s\n",mKey,mData);
        cin.ignore(80,'\n'), cin.get();
        //InsertIntoHT (ht, mKey, mData);
    }

    fclose(inFile);

    WriteHTtoDisk(ht, "hashTable.dat");
    ReportHT (ht,"BEFORE");

    return 0;
}

void WriteHTtoDisk (HASHTABLE ht, char *HashDisk)
{
    FILE * HASHDISK = fopen(HashDisk, "rb");
    int maxBkt = 30;
    int maxSlot = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxBkt; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxSlot; j++)
        {
            fwrite(ht.pBkt[i].entry[j].key,11,sizeof(maxSlot),HASHDISK);
            fwrite(ht.pBkt[i].entry[j].data,21,sizeof(maxSlot),HASHDISK);
        }

    }
}

void ReportHT (HASHTABLE ht, char * when)
{
    int maxB = 30;
    int maxS = 3;
    cout << "Hash Table \n" << "Verification Report \n" << when << " Restoration" << endl;

    for (int b = 0; b < maxB; b++)
    {
        cout << "Bucket " << (b+1) << endl;

        if (b < 20)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxS; i++)
            {
                cout << setw(3) << "Slot " << (i+1) << ": " << ht.pBkt[b].entry[i].key << setw(3) << ht.pBkt[b].entry[i].data << endl;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxS; i++)
            {
                cout << setw(3) << "Slot " << (i+1) << ": " << ht.oBkt[b].entry[i].key << setw(3) << ht.oBkt[b].entry[i].data << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles with no problems, but when I inspect the file, I find that it is all just gibberish and weird symbols. The data I am using was previously extracted from another file and I want to save it in the format in which it was inserted. I am sure the issue is with the lines with fwrite (I am not that experienced with C syntax as I am with C++).

The data was in the DATAIN.dat file like this:

TATUNG CO.EL PR. LONG BEACH CA
KAMERMAN LCIRRUS BEAVERTON, OR
QUADRAM COLOACH AV NORCROSS GE
AST RESEARALTON AV IRVINE   CA

I am expecting the new file to look like this:

TATUNG CO.
EL PR. LONG BEACH CA

KAMERMAN L
CIRRUS BEAVERTON, OR

QUADRAM CO
LOACH AV NORCROSS GE

AST RESEAR
ALTON AV IRVINE   CA

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try to make a [mcve] and post it in your question, instead of posting parts of your code. Make sure the problem can be reproduced. Don't forget to write which output you expect. Doing this could lead you to a solution. If not, [edit] your question, so it becomes answerable.

Comment: Should I add the original text file? What else can I do for clarification?

Comment: Would I need to include the text file I want to read from? Sorry, I'm new to this site.

Comment: [mcve] means, among other things,  "minimal example which reproduces". You can follow this link to read what people expect from your example. I see that you added your whole program; it's better than part, but even better would be to make your example minimal! Imagine people wondering: "Where is the problematic code? Is it in `InsertIntoHT` or in `WriteHTtoDisk`?" The idea in "minimal" is that you answer this question (where the problem is) by yourself, using the method of elimination. Reduce your code to minimum. Don't forget to make a backup before you start deleting irrelevant code.

Comment: I think I've reduced it enough to show what the problem is. The bunched-up text in the example can be put into a .dat file and run. I'm not sure how to attach the full text file.

Comment: Do you find that when reading input, you get character misalignment?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm pretty sure the code for reading from the file was revised so that everything aligns.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code doesn't initialize or even use the member `count`. When a hash bucket is empty, the `count` should indicate it. In C++ it's easy to implement: just add `= 0` to its definition:

```
struct BUCKET
{
  SLOT entry[3];
  int count = 0;
  BUCKET* overflow;
};
```

Also, when writing the bucket's data to a file, use the count and don't assume that all the entries in the bucket are filled.

```
        for (int j = 0; j < ht.pBkt[i].count; j++)
            ...
```

Also, write only the required number of bytes. `fwrite` accepts two parameters: the size of the data elements to write and their number. Here, the size is 11 or 21, and the number is 1, because each `fwrite` call can only write one string to your file.

```
            fwrite(ht.pBkt[i].entry[j].key,11,1,HASHDISK);
            fwrite(ht.pBkt[i].entry[j].data,21,1,HASHDISK);
```

By the way, since you have a `STR10` type, you can avoid magic numbers and write `sizeof(STR10)` instead of `11`. This way, when you change the length of your string, your code will still work.

Comment: It's still giving the same error. And when I run the code with the edits in the full program, it suddenly stops working.